# Crear un método que me permita guardar ciertos registros antes de ser actualizados en otro modelo en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un modelo donde guardo sus atributos y ahora, necesito guardar algunos de los atributos de ese modelo en otro diferente que he decidido llamar ModelVersions y sería el que guarde los registros antes de que sean actualizados en el método update del controlador Modelo.

La migración del modelo original es el siguiente:

```
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :models do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :address
   t.string :description
   t.integer :planning_day
   t.boolean :is_enable, default: true
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Y la del modelo donde planeo guardar el histórico o versiones del anterior es (con algunos atributos del modelo anterior pero NO todos):

```
class CreateModelVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :model_versions do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.integer :planning_day
   t.references :model, foreign_key: true

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Pienso que en el modelo que guardaría las versiones debería crear un método que me permita guardar los atributos antes de actualizarlo por lo que se me ocurre algo como esto:

```
class ModelVersion < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :model

 before_update :save_model_version

end
```

Pero no sé como hacer el método para que guarde la data antes de actualizarla en el controlador. **Dándole algunas vueltas se me ha ocurrido algo como lo siguiente:**

```
    def save_model_version model_id
     if self.model_version.include? model_id
      @model_version = ModelVersion.create(:name,:planning_day)
     end
    end
  end
```

Sin embargo si estuviera en el camino correcto aún no consigo comprender como debería llamarlo en el controlador de modelo.

Y ese método llamarlo dentro de la acción update dentro del controller de Models (app/controllers/models_controller.rb):

```
  def update

    if @model.update(model_params)
      render json: @model
    else
      render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
   end
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los métodos del módulo [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty) deberían ayudarte para lo que necesitas, como `.attribute_was`, que te permite ver el valor que tenía antiguamente un atributo específico. Lo llamas con el nombre de tu atributo y agregándole `_was` al final:

```
[19] pry(main)> cf.order
=> 6
[20] pry(main)> cf.order = 7
=> 7
[21] pry(main)> cf.order_was
=> 6
```

Hay otros métodos que pueden serte útiles de igual forma, como `.attribute_change` que te permite ver los valores anterior y actual del registro:

```
[22] pry(main)> cf.order_change
=> [6, 7]
```

o `.changed?` que te perite ver si el registro ha sido modificado o no

```
[21] pry(main)> cf.changed?
=> true
```

Y por último `.changed_attributes` que te muestra cuáles atributos de tu registro han sido modificados:

```
[23] pry(main)> cf.changed_attributes
=> {"order"=>6}
```

Con esto podrías hacer algo como:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :model_versions

  before_update :save_model_version

  def save_model_version
    # no hay necesidad de crear un registro si no han habido cambios
    return unless changed? 

    # crea una nueva version con los valores antiguos de model
    model_versions.create(name: name_was, planning_day: planning_day_was)
  end
end
```

Ojo, que desde donde deberías llamar el callback es desde el modelo `Model` y no `ModelVersion` como lo pusiste en tu pregunta.

Comment: @Alter_Lagos muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tal vez no formulé correctamente mi pregunta, los métodos que mencionas son para realizar la consulta en rails c. En este caso en particular debo crear un método en la acción update del controlador del Modelo que me permita antes de realizar un update crear(guardar) ciertos atributos en el otro modelo que llamé ModelVersions. He editado mi pregunta a ver si puede ser más aclaratoria :)

Comment: @Polarwinds los métodos que menciono son para ejecutarlos en cualquier parte, no solo en la consola de rails. Eso te lo mostré como ejemplo para que vieras tú como hacerlo en tu propio código, pero bueno, revisa mi respuesta actualizada que te muestro también como puedas implementarlo. Saludos

Comment: @Alter_Lagos muchas gracias por la explicación me ha sido de gran ayuda.